# Connect to a form with changing values with HttpClient in Java

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to connect to a URL with a form that has this values:

http://aulavirtual.uv.es/

How can I do this if every time I log value changes (time, token_id, hash) ? Please, help me !! I try with HttpUrlConnection and now with HttpClient 4.

```
 <form name="login" method="post" action="/register/">
  <input type="hidden" name="form:mode" value="edit">
  <input type="hidden" name="form:id" value="login">
  <input type="hidden" name="__confirmed_p" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="__refreshing_p" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="/dotlrn/index">
  <input type="hidden" name="time" value="1352222384">
  <input type="hidden" name="token_id" value="423">
  <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="3F8865DB5E6603C296428A5A7C0D66C0256D5626">
      <tr>
            <td class="formulari">Nom d'usuari</td>
            <td class="formulari">
               <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" size="25" alt="Nom d'usuari"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <TD class="formulari">Contrasenya</TD>
            <TD class="formulari">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="25" ALT="Contrasenya d'accés"></TD>
      </tr>
      <TR>
            <TD COLSPAN="2"  class="formulari1">
               <div align="center">
                 <input id="login" type="submit" value="     Entreu      " alt="Entrar al Aula Virtual">
                 <A HREF="https://aulavirtual.uv.es"><IMG BORDER="0" HEIGHT="25" WIDTH="25" SRC="/resources/key.gif" ALT="Entrar en modo seguro" TITLE="Entrar en modo seguro"></A>
               </div>
            <!--
            <Table COLSPAN="2"  class="fonsgifs">
              <div align="center" class="titol3">
              <strong><A HREF="/altrescursos" class="font2nivell"><U>Altres cursos acad&egrave;mics</U></A></SPAN></strong>
            </table>
              <BR><BR><BR>
              <CENTER>
            -->
            <!--
              <A HREF="/dotlrn/clubs/openacslrnconference/xowiki/"><img align="center" src="/images/cabeceraOPEN.png" border = 0 align="center" alt="Conferencia OPEN" /></a>

              <BR><A HREF="/dotlrn/clubs/openacslrnconference/xowiki/"><img align="center" src="/images/ConferenciaSofwareLibre.png" border = 0 align="center" alt="Conferencia Software Libre" /></a>
              <BR><A HREF="/dotlrn/clubs/openacslrnconference/xowiki/">7th OpenACS / .LRN Conference </A> 
              <BR><A HREF="/dotlrn/clubs/openacslrnconference/xowiki/">Conferencia sobre Software Libre en Educación Superior</A>                   
              </CENTER>
            -->
        </TD>
        </TR>

      <TR>
            <TD  class="formulari1" COLSPAN="2" style="text-align:center">

            <BR><BR><BR>
            </TD>
      </TR>
    </FORM>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This form uses hidden parameters for security purposes.  Every time http://aulavirtual.uv.es/ is displayed these hidden parameters change.

You could try changing your code to do the following:

1. GET the http://aulavirtual.uv.es/ page.
2. Parse the resulting HTML to extract the values of the `time`, `token_id`, and `hash` hidden parameters from the form element.
3. Do the POST as you do now, but pass in these three values instead of the fixed values you are using now.

Comment: Ok, this was my first option. I tried to parse the HTML, but with jericho-html-3.2.jar I can´t do that because of connection established I think is different than the original with GET, how can I do? Is the same connection after this when I send the POST? I'm trying, if I solve this I will post it ! 
I accept more suggestions !

Comment: With Jericho you have two choices (1) user the `Source(URL)` constructor and have Jericho handle the initial GET request or (2) use HttpClient 4 to open the GET request and then use `Source(Reader)` or `Source(InputStream)` to parse the HTML. Once you have extracted out the hidden parameters you can then use HttpClient 4 to open a new POST request to pass in the form information.  These will be two totally different requests.